# Stack bar chart using pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have some data with 3 columns from which I will like to plot stack bars showing increasing date on y axis and counts of numbers (based on Column "Numbers"); so the stacks in the bars continents (Column "Continent") stacked on each other and legend coloured by continent.

Here's the data:

```
Date    Numbers Country
22/03/2020  2   AFRICA
22/03/2020  4   AFRICA
22/03/2020  10  AFRICA
23/03/2020  4   ASIA
23/03/2020  6   ASIA
23/03/2020  15  ASIA
24/03/2020  2   AMERICA
24/03/2020  7   AMERICA
24/03/2020  17  AMERICA
25/03/2020  5   EUROPE
25/03/2020  15  EUROPE
25/03/2020  20  EUROPE
26/03/2020  3   OCEANIA
26/03/2020  4   OCEANIA
26/03/2020  10  OCEANIA
```

Here's my attempt that did not work:

```
df.index=df['Date']
df_c= df.groupby(['Country'])['Number'].count()
df_c.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Can someone help please? Thanks

EDIT: date on x-axis and sum of Numbers on y axis

Comment: It is not clear how you want your chart?  What is on the x-axis?

Comment: @Scott Boston please see my EDIT above

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
df.groupby(['Date','Country'])['Numbers'].count().unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang You're nearly there, I want the continents together in one bar, that is all continent colours in one bar for each date date.

Comment: Yes, that's what the code does. In this case, you only have one continent per date in your sample data, so different columns happens to depict  different continents